# Capturing mutable entities reference across contexts in domain driven design

Tags: domain-driven-design

When events in one context trigger events and status changes other context, typically through message passing, how do you capture easily the fact that your triggered event in a bounded context B was originated by some events from A and potentially by the state of A at some point in time?

Let's imagine the following scenario:

- You have a first microservice `Account` with aggregate root `AccountRoot`, with a given ID
- You have a second microservice `Customer` with aggregate root `CustomerRoot`, with a given ID
- You have a third microservice `Terms` with aggregate root `Terms` , where `TermsRoot` is itself a collection of aggregates `Proposal`, each computed from an instance of `Customer` and an instance of `Account`. An event of type `AccountUpdated` or `CustomerUpdated` triggers a new `Proposal`.

Now you have the following problem:

1. You need to keep track of which values you used to create your instance of `Proposal`
2. You need to make `Terms` **idempotent**: you don't want that processing twice the same `AccountUpdated`, maybe because `Terms` crushed or `Account` publishes twice the same event.

These two problems leads to these two questions:

1. Storing only the id of `AccountRoot` and `CustomerRoot` inside a `Proposal` will not work because their state is mutable. You have two options: store some timestamp or some sort of index which allows you to fully identify the state of `AccountRoot` and `CustomerRoot` (which you will need to rebuild from their journal) or store the full state, which will make things much easier. However, would not this be polluting the bounded context `Terms`?
2. The creation of `Proposal` is idempotent with respect to a given state of `Customer` and `Account`. However, the state in DDD has no ID, so it is difficult to determine if you have already created the `Proposal`. We were considering using some sort of hash function of `Customer` and `Account` state. How do you solve this issue?

Comment: "You need to keep track of which values you used to create your instance of Proposal" - why? Who needs it?

Comment: Well how can you make idempotent if not?

Comment: Why did you cite "keeping track of values" as problem #1 and then idempotence as problem #2 if what you want is idempotence in the first place and tracking values is only a means to an end?

Comment: Also, idempotence with regards to what? You didn't give a domain-related definition of what makes an operation "the same" in the eyes of `Terms`. For instance, are two identical `AccountUpdated` with an 8 month time gap (or 2 years, or whatever) considered the same? If so, why?

Comment: Very good point, in fact the are not. I need idempotence with respect to multiple processing of the same "pair" of events

Comment: The business reason seems somewhat nebulous. Can you elaborate on why that is?

Comment: Absolutely, every time a new proposal is generated, a human will take an action: it might call the client, telling him there are new conditions available for him.

Comment: I'm talking about the reason for a `Proposal` being spawned only from a unique pair of `AccountUpdated` / `CustomerUpdated` events, if I understood correctly. How often does `AccountUpdated` come up vs `CustomerUpdated`? How do they alternate? What's the business meaning of all this?

Comment: Plus, what is the business risk / cost of "duplicate" `Proposals` being created?

Comment: Overwork on business people

Comment: What about my previous question? Is there a business meaning to all this or do you just feel like you need to protect yourself from potential accidents in message/event delivery?

Comment: The business meaning is that a Proposal triggers an Offer, and you do not want to smash the client with offers because you re-processed the same event

Comment: Way before that in the process, why would two pair of identical events be emitted in the first place? Is it just because users would go to the Edit screen for an `Account` or a `Customer`, not change anything and save?

Comment: My event framework has at least once semantic

Answer (score 2):

I never had this need, but I think I would try with a versioning system, publishing the version with the event `(Account|Customer)Updated`, so that in your read model, you can have the id and the version of the entity that generated it.
You can have a version per entity, that is incremented in each event.

About publishing the version, it would be a metadata of the event (in pair with the id of the entity).

With this informations in the event (and the entire events history) it shouldn't be hard to have a process populating a read model with all the data you need (the relationships plus the state of the entity at that version).

To make the operation idempotent, as you said, you can try to generate the id using an hash of the input (or a part of your input), and check if it already exists in the handler of the event that generate the `Proposal`.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand from your business requirements, the Proposal is not from the Write side but in fact an Entity from the Read side, possibly grouped by some TermId.

When the Proposal entity is created (by those two events), it uses data from other two read models: the list of all Accounts and the list of all Customers. From there it loads by ID the two read entities and queries them for the required state. Composing a read entity from multiple other read entities is often found in CQRS architectures. This, however, creates a dependency to other two read models. Also, you have hard problems in case the Read model needs a complete rebuild.

Another solution that mitigates these problems would be that the Proposal read model maintains a private, independent state built from the Account and Customer events. When the Proposal entity is created, this private state is used.  This solution builds the most resilient system.

Note that no Aggregate is used, only the Read side or events are involved. In this way, the Aggregate's encapsulation is protected.

> You need to make Terms idempotent
>
> ...
>
> However, the state in DDD has no ID, so it is difficult to determine if you have already created the Proposal. We were considering using some sort of hash function of Customer and Account state. How do you solve this issue?

You can do this by computing a hash from the two events creation time and Aggregate's ID and creating an unique index on the persistence.

> However, would not this be polluting the bounded context Terms?

Using the events generated from a remote bounded context does not ever pollute the local bounded context. This is because the interpretation of those events is local, they have effect in the local context according to the local context rules.

Also, using domain events as a integration technique is one of the recommended ways, if not the best.

Comment: Why do you say the Proposal is not a write side entity? It is an entity under the root aggregate of Terms : 1  terms instance for every pair (account, customer) => Multiple Proposals as the account and customer data for a single account and customer vary over time

Comment: @Edmondo1984 Yes, they vary, but they are not used in Write side decisions by the Terms Aggregate, are they? Not everything that varies is write side entity. This is true for CQRS or Event-based architectures (and you have&use Domain events). At least this is what you presented. Do you have other business rules that you didn't tell about?

Comment: Yes I am sorry: when a client connects to the website, he needs to get the last available proposal for himself. So the Term Entity will in fact has the same id as the Customer ID, and its state needs to be updated when a new Proposal is computed